# NGINX webserver can't resolve hostname

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, hostname

I'm trying to create a simple website-database-setup. A webserver (NGINX) with an angular application in Pod A accesses a REST-API and Database in Pod B via a service (loading some items). Unfortunately, every time I try load my website and it tries to access Pod B via the service, I get "NS_ERROR_UNNKNOWN_HOST" from the browser.

**My GKE-K8-setup is as follows:**

Ingress -> Service1 -> Nginx webserver with angular application (Pod A) -> Service2 -> REST-API/Database (Pod B)

Interestingly, accessing Pod B via `curl` from Pod A works without any problems (and I get an answer back). `nslookup` works as well.

```
/ # curl http://exampleapp-backend/api/items
[{"id":0,"title":"tiletitletitle","content":"contentcontentcontent"}]
```

```
/ # nslookup exampleapp-backend
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve
Name:      exampleapp-backend
Address 1: 10.60.12.182 exampleapp-backend.default.svc.cluster.local
```

The code, which calls the API from my angular app looks like this:

```
public GET_items(): Observable<Item[]> {
    return this.http.get<Item[]>("http://exampleapp-backend.default.svc.cluster.local/api/items")
  }
```

If I replace the FQDN of the service with its IP (10.60.12.182) the results are not much different (I get a timeout after ~ 20 seconds instead of the error mentioned above).

All the kube-dns services and deployments are running, they don't show any errors in their logs and `/etc/resolv.conf` seems to be correct as well.

**/etc/resolv.conf**

```
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local europe-west3-a.c.t-selfsrv-backstage-poc-7a9f.internal c.t-selfsrv-backstage-poc-7a9f.internal google.internal
nameserver 10.60.0.10
options ndots:5
```

**NGINX conf:**

```
events {}

http {

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

  server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
}
```

**Frontend deployment (Pod A):**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: exampleapp-frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: exampleapp-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: exampleapp-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: angular
        image: <nginx-image-with-angularApp>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: exampleapp-secrets
```

**Service to Pod B**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: exampleapp-backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: exampleapp-backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

**Backend deployment (Pod B)**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: exampleapp-backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: exampleapp-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: exampleapp-backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api
        image: <image-with-api>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: exampleapp-secrets
```

Do I need to add something to my nginx.conf? (I am very new to setting up nginx). There are some other threads here on stackoverflow as well with similar problems, they are using the nginx-sever as a reverse proxy though (which is not the case here, so the actual problem might be a bit different?).

**Thing's I've tried:**

- searched for similar problems on google/stackoverflow
- tried various combinations of the FQDN of the service (without trailing slashes, leaving out the ".default.svc.cluster.local" part
- replaced the FQDN with its corresponding IP
- made sure kube-dns services/deployments are up and running and show no errors
- restarted kube-dns deployments
- made sure `resolv.conf` is properly configured
- made sure hostname resolution works with `curl` and `nslookup`

Comment: It seems to me that the issue is with the Angular app. It's just a front-end client app or it's being served by a node server like express?

Comment: @Hackerman It's just a front-end client app (I think). The Angular App was built with node and the resulting package was copied into /usr/share/nginx/html of the nginx.

Comment: That's the problem with static apps on k8s....once they get served are basically executed on your computer....there is now way to reach the ther pod, because there is no server side communication....simple solution should be to just deploy the static app in the app engine and then expose the k8s api to the outside world using an Ingress controller, and add CORS rules to allow request just from your static app origin.

Comment: @Hackerman Ohhh, right! Got it, thank you! I was able to implement a working solution!